# Are there plans for a scope for Personal Information Management?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, organizer

For Ubuntu touch/phone there are a number of core apps for different purposes like calendar, contacts, notes, etc. Unfortunately there's no scope to combine these seperate apps into a single "Personal Information Management"-Environment like for example Thunderbird, MS Outlook or Open-Xchange.
Are there plans to get there someday?

Answer (score 0):

**Today scope** is mean to be *"personal information manager"*. You can select  *(in options)*  displaying upcoming events (`calendar`), favorite `contacts`, upcoming tasks (`notes`) recent msg, calls and many more (`etc`).  It would not be fair to compare this to Thunderbird or Outlook yet, but it's so far ubuntu's best way of managing daily personal information.